# I got an infinite loading when trying to throw error with node/express typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, error-handling

This route suppose to throw error when hit:

```js
app.get('/error', (req: Express.Request, res: Express.Response) => {
  throw new Error();
});
```

then when I hit `/error` I got an infinite loop

I work with `node version 16.13.1`, `npm version 8.3.0` and `typescript version 4.5.4`

NB: If needed, I can provide the code inside package.json, tsconfig.json or other file

Comment: Do. you have any middleware that handles errors ?

Comment: No, I don't because I thought `throw new Error()` is by default handled by express